# How do I authenticate with Firebase Auth without any json files?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase-authentication

I am working on a system and trying to implement authentication with Firebase Auth.

I see that Google generates private keys on json files. And it works fine authenticating with them according to [this tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup/)

Basically setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to the path where the keys are contained.

Or sending the data manually like this:

```js
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://my-firebase-project.firebaseio.com"
});
```

However I don't want to hold any physical files. Our entire stack is automated (aside from certain keys that are set as ENV vars from an external parameter store), and as such everything sits in source control, but I don't want to upload a key file to source control.

How do I authenticate with Firebase Auth without the use of any physical files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason you couldn't set keys with environment variables.

Use `process.env.VAR_NAME` to get environment variables from within your Node.js application.

Comment: But the `admin-sdk` doesn't work with keys, it only works by reading a file

Comment: @RodrigoSasaki Nowhere in your code above are you passing in a path to a file to some SDK.  You're calling `require()`, which is just going to parse the JSON and return the object it contains.  `admin.initializeApp()` doesn't know or care where the data comes from.

Comment: how did you manage this, I am having the same problem, did you set the object as an .env variable then parse it somehow? thanks